# CSS animation Ends Wrong

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I wrote this small CSS animation to rotate an element 30 degrees. It works well, except when the animation finishes, it goes back to 0 degrees instead of staying at 30.

My intention is to show the element rotating, then having it stay there, not go back to start. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
div.pointer {
    animation: pointer 3s;
}

@keyframes pointer {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Set `animation-fill-mode: forwards`. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, Harry, for the answer. I did try searching before asking but wasn't able to find an answer until now. Thanks again.